# I asked a question about arrays before, but this one won't compile

Tags: java

I asked about this array a little while ago, and I can't see what the problem is. Too tired.  What have I done wrong?  Basically, I am taking a string array and trying to check to see if it contains numbers or an x (ISBN number validation).  I want to take the number from a given input (bookNum), check the input, and feed any valid input into a new array (book).  At the line

```
'bookNum.charAt[j]==book[i]'
```

I get the 'not  a statement error'.  What gives?

```
  String[] book = new String [ISBN_NUM];
  bookNum.replaceAll("-","");
  if (bookNum.length()!=ISBN_NUM)
    throw new ISBNException ("ISBN "+ bookNum + " must be 10 characters");
  for (int i=0;i<bookNum.length();i++)
  {
      if (Character.isDigit(bookNum.charAt(i)))
      bookNum.CharAt[j]==book[i];
      j++;
      if (book[9].isNotDigit()|| 
          book[9]!="x"        ||
          book[9]!="X")
      throw new ISBNException ("ISBN " + bookNum + " must contain all digits" + 
                               "or 'X' in the last position");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few odd problems here.  For starters, did you mean for book to be an array of Strings, as opposed to just one string?  You're trying (assuming CharAt was written properly and the assignment was proper) to assign a character to a string.

Second, instead of copying character by character, why not check the whole string, and copy the whole thing at the end if it is a proper ISBN?  Depending on what you do with Exceptions (if you continue regardless), you could add a boolean as a flag that gets set if there is an error.  At the end, if there is no error, then make book = to booknumber.replace(etc...)

Comment: Like I said, it depends what your course of action is upon meeting an invalid ISBN.  Also, I can't tell where your for loop is closing, but it would seem like you check the 10th character (index 9) on every iteration.  I would check that the whole string minus the last character is numeric, then check the last character (numeric or X), then either return it, do whatever you're supposed to do on failure if it isn't valid, or copy it to a new string if that's what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you for your help, and pardon my language above.  I will edit that out.  The whole point of this exercise is to learn how to create custom exceptions.  So all i am doing is checking the given number, throwing out an exception if it doesn't meet the criteria, and then after that, I check to see if the check digit is correct. If all is well, I write a little thing saying that it is indeed valid. Oh, yeah, I noticed that the loop wasn't closed in the proper spot, took care of that, thanks.

Comment: Then, it doesn't seem like you need to store it/copy it anywhere at all.  Just iterate through every character of the original string (except for the last one), throw exception if needed, and check the last one.  Why even create the "word" string at all?

Answer (score 5):

== is java is used for equivalence comparison. If you want to assign it, use a single =.

Answer (score 2):

The first issue here is that `charAt` is a function, and thus needs parenthesis even though you are accessing with an index like an array.

The other issue is that the line is a boolean expression, which just by itself does not mean anything. A lot of people are suggestion that you mean to make an assignment to that character, but just changing to a single equals causes other problems. The left side of an equals sign needs to be a variable, and the result of a function is not a variable.

Strings are immutable, so you can not simply change one of the characters in the string. Earlier in your code, you have a call to `replaceAll()`, that returns a new string with the alterations. As written, this altered string is being lost.

Comment: +1: only answer here that actually makes sense (accounts for `charAt` being a function, `==` being equality not assignment, and `Strings` being immutable).

Comment: I agree. My answer was nonsense; I focused on the `==` and completely missed that `charAt` is not something that can be assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

```
  bookNum.CharAt[j]==book[i];
```

Should be

```
  bookNum.CharAt[j]=book[i];
```

You are using an equality boolean operator, not an assignment one.

Answer (score 1):

The line `bookNum.CharAt[j]==book[i];` isn't a statement. It's a comparison. Perhaps you want `bookNum.CharAt[j]=book[i];` (single `=` instead of `==`).

Edit: That's not going to fix things, though, since you can't assign to `bookNum.CharAt[j]`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using .charAt(i) wrong! Assuming that "bookNum" is a String, you should use:

```
bookNum.charAt(i)==book[i];
```

Instead. Note that this is a boolean expression, and not "=".

Comment: Now I am getting a unexpected type require:variable found: value

Comment: I looked at your code again, and it looks like you want to set "books[i]" **equal to** bookNum.charAt(i). In that case, it should be, 'books[i] = bookNum.charAt(i)'. However, I'm guessing this will give you an error, unless books[] is an array of chars. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this statement?

Comment: I need to figure out if the characters in the bookNum string are numbers(or the last character is a number or an x).  It is being used to validate ISBN numbers.