# Can't replace a letter in a string

Tags: java

I have asked a couple of questions about this for loop:

```
  String[] book = new String [ISBN_NUM];
  bookNum.replaceAll("-","");
  if (bookNum.length()!=ISBN_NUM)
    throw new ISBNException ("ISBN "+ bookNum + " must be 10 characters");
  for (int i=0;i<bookNum.length();i++)
  {
      if (Character.isDigit(bookNum.charAt(i)))
      book[j]=bookNum.charAt(i);  //this is the problem right here
      j++;
      if (book[9].isNotDigit()|| 
          book[9]!="x"        ||
          book[9]!="X")
      throw new ISBNException ("ISBN " + bookNum + " must contain all digits" + 
                               "or 'X' in the last position");
  }
```

which will not compile.  An answer I had from the other question I asked told me that the line where the error occurs is wrong in that bookNum.charAt(i) is an (immutable) string, and I can't get the values into a book array that way.  What I need to do on my assignment is check an ISBN number (bookNum) to see that it is all numbers, except the last digit can be an 'x' (valid ISBN). Is this the best way to do it?  If so, what the hell am I doing wrong?  If not, what method would be a better one to use?

Comment: instead of writing "which will not compile" state the actual error message from the compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`book` is of type `String[]` (array of strings), `bookNum.charAt(i)` returns a `char`. You can't assign a `String` from a `char`.

Do `book[j] = String.valueOf(bookNum.charAt(i))` instead.

Also you might want to change the first error:

```
throw new ISBNException ("ISBN "+ bookNum + " must be " + ISBN_NUM + " characters");
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is wrong with that part?  (The throwing of the error)

Comment: Well you hardcode the value "10" but you have a symbolic constant with the same value representing the same thing. You should use the constant in all places where you mean "the number of digits in an ISBN". Probably want to use ISBN_NUM - 1 instead of 9 for the array indexes too.

Comment: I get it for the array indexes, thanks.  Can't see where I have the number 10 hard coded, other than in the String I am trying to return for the Exception. I am tired, however, so I am sure I am even missing stuff like that, too.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about, in the string you emit.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Our assignment is fairly specific in terms of the text, so I'm kinda stuck on that one.

Comment: It doesn't affect the output.

Answer (score 3):

The book[] array contains Strings.

The method bookNum.charAt() returns a char.

You can't assign a char to a member of a String array.

If you want an array of Strings, consider using bookNum.substring( i, i + 1 ).

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is that you declare book as a String Array instead of just a String.

Comment: Yes, but I need the separate elements (most will be numbers, this is used to validate a bunch of numbers) in an array, and I have to use String in case the last character is 'x'.

Comment: You have to search all characters in one String. String[] book contains many books. String book would be for one book. And then you go book.charAt(i) to pick the characters. book[9] the way you have it would be the tenth book. You need book.charAt(9) for the tenth character. Did you learn C before you started with Java? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem :

```
String[] book = new String [ISBN_NUM];
```

You create an array of String objects, but then you feed it with chars :

```
book[j]=bookNum.charAt(i);
```

Just initialize the array like this :

```
char[] book = new char[ISBN_NUM];
```

Furthermore, you should get rid of your `j` variable that does the same as `i`. And end the `for` loop before checking `book[9]` or you will get a `NullPointerException`.

Hopefully there are not any more problems :)

Comment: I'm sure there will be, but thanks for the help on these ones.  How do I check to make sure the char is not a digit or an x?

Comment: @unit The best way to express your thanks is to cast an upvote :)

Comment: I understand that.  I apologize for actually trying to fix my problem before doling out the precious ten points. Trust me, it was coming.

Comment: @unit - Don't forget that we are doing you a favour by spending time to answering your questions ... not the other way around.  Snarky comments about "doling out precious points" are not called for, IMO.

Comment: *"How do I check to make sure the char is not a digit or an x?"* - Hint: you could an `if` statement, the `<`, '&&' and '||' operators, and your knowledge of the value ranges of the ASCII digit characters.  Or you could use a `switch` statement.

Comment: I do understand that you guys help.  But sometimes, it seems like there are people playing a big techie mmo trying to get their points before a guy even has a chance to implement a solution. I appreciate the help more than you can imagine.  I just don't like being chastised for something I haven't even really had a chance to do. I'll ask my wife to do that.

Answer (score 1):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035179/i-asked-a-question-about-arrays-before-but-this-one-wont-compile/5035915#5035915) in your other thread.
You are basically treating an array of strings like a string (or array of characters).  What is your goal here?  You just want to validate that the bookNum is a valid ISBN, correct?  What is the course of action if it is not?  If your goal is to take the whole bookNum if it is valid and abort if it isn't, my answer in the other thread should give hints as to a possibly better way to do that.